# SQL Server 2008 Help - Find constant + Primary key

Tags: sql-server-2008

Using a SQL Server 2008 database, I am trying to find rows in column B that don't match a constant piece of data + primary key. Where primary Key is column A
Here's an example where I am looking for a SQL statement that will retrieve row 3 from this table:

<kbd>Row xxx</kbd><kbd>Column A</kbd><kbd>Column B</kbd>
<kbd>Row 1</kbd>     <kbd>123</kbd>       <kbd>od123</kbd>      
<kbd>Row 2</kbd>      <kbd>124</kbd>      <kbd>od124</kbd>      
<kbd>Row 3</kbd>      <kbd>125</kbd>       <kbd>od789</kbd>      
<kbd>Row 4</kbd>      <kbd>126</kbd>       <kbd>od126</kbd>

Alias the table and compare? Create a view? Is there a way to use concatenate?

Thanks in advance

Comment: ok i added a more proper table

Comment: `WHERE ColumnB <> 'od' + CAST(ColumnA AS VARCHAR(10))`?

Comment: Hey thank you for the responses! these worked great. I was overthinking this.

Answer (score 0):

Replace my variables with whatever column names you are using...

```
declare @columna varchar(20)
set @columna = '125'
declare @columnb varchar(20)
set @columnb = 'od789'
select len(@columnb) - len(replace(@columnb,@columna,''))
```

If the result of `select len(@columnb) - len(replace(@columnb,@columna,''))` = 0 you can take the result (meaning it does not exist in the string).  If however the result > 0 you do not want to pick that up, for example, using your data:

```
declare @columna varchar(20)
set @columna = '123'
declare @columnb varchar(20)
set @columnb = 'od123'
select len(@columnb) - len(replace(@columnb,@columna,''))
```

Would return 3.

A more general solution could be:

`SELECT <enter your columns that you want to return here> 
 FROM 
      YourTable 
 WHERE 
      len(columnb) - len(replace(columnb,columna,''))=0`

The idea here is if there is no replacement to be done you end up with the length of the original string (column b) subtracted from the original string (again column b, since nothing has changed), this is the data you want returned (WHERE... = 0).

On the other hand if a replacement is made within the string you end up getting a positive length (even if the strings are exact, try it with od123 and od123), this in turn should be discarded from your result set.  This is why I filtered in the where condition using = 0.